# getting errors when i try to initialize my datadir on Oracle mysql 5.7

Tags: database, centos7, mysql-5.7

So I am configuring mysql to run multiple instances.

when I try to initialize the datadir I get this error.

```
# mysql_install_db --user=mysql --  datadir=/var/lib/mysql/mysql1
[WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please   consider switching to mysqld --initialize
[ERROR]   The data directory '/var/lib/mysql/mysql1'   already exist and is not empty.

# mysql_install_db --user=mysql --  datadir=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2
[WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please   consider switching to mysqld --initialize
[WARNING] The bootstrap log isn't empty:
[WARNING] 2015-12-14T15:15:33.485673Z 0 [Warning] --  bootstrap is deprecated. Please consider using --initialize instead
[Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files:   1024 (requested 5000)
[Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache:  431 (requested 2000)
```

Comment: I am having a very similar problem, have you found a solution yet?